# Embedded HTML code in Python string doesn't appear properly in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm facing a problem when I embed HTML code in my python's view.py
Basically, my objective is to customize the color of certain words only (based on the input). I want to do it by modifying the view.py

For example (my view.py):

```py
def home(request):
    form = request.POST.get('uncorrected')
    texts  = str(form) + '<span style="color: red">test text but this section is red</span>'
    return render(request, 'corrector/home.html', {'text': texts})
```

Inside my index.html:

```html
<textarea type="text" id="textarea" name="uncorrected">
        {{ text }}
</textarea>
```

However, when I type "my text" in the textarea it displays only:

```
my text <span style="color: red">test text but this section is red</span>
```

It doesn't make the text red, it directly displays the code.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically escapes HTML to prevent XSS attacks. In order to render HTML as HTML, you just pipe in `safe`.

```html
{{ text|safe }}
```

Django will still escape the HTML, but it will render it as well

Comment: Thanks, however, it still gives me the same thing: ```Text<span style="color: red">test text but this section is red</span>```. It is not rendered in red.

Comment: Can we see the traceback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand. There are no errors, it just show me the same thing as before

Comment: It could be that `safe` is escaping your span. Try using a `p` tag

Comment: Now it shows me ```Text<p style="color: red">test text but this section is red</p>```... Is it a problem that I do this inside a textarea?

Comment: Yes. Textarea cannot render HTML. Change the `textarea` to a `p`

Comment: Yes, but then the user can't edit this, right? Is there another way?

Comment: The only other way I can think of is using Javascript

Comment: Is it compatible with doing all the stuff with Python and Django?

Comment: Any updates here ? getting the same issue